# how to focus angularjs ui-select input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

myProblem is I have a box modal that have ui-select dropdown.
when the modal come iwant myUser can choose oneOf the item with keyboard.
but focus is not on modal.
how can i focus on input(important, input) of ui-select?
thanks alot.

```
<ui-select class="cursorISI aaa  selectType2 border-fixed" 
    on-select="Func.selectAnotherProject($item, $model)" theme="selectize"
    ng-model="oldSelectedProject"> <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.title}}
</ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices
    repeat="project in  projectList|filter: $select.search "
    refresh-delay="0" style="direction: ltr; text-align: right;">

<div ng-bind="project.title"
    ng-show="runSelectedProject.uid!=project.uid"></div>
</ui-select-choices> </ui-select>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, it's fairly simple. A simple look at the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select) will tell you this.

autofocus: Automatically get focus when loaded. Default value is 'false'

So, just add that to the first line of your html like `<ui-select class="cursorISI aaa  selectType2 border-fixed" autofocus="true"`

Hope this helps - Cheers

Comment: This is not working for the input text inside the UI select. Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to focus on demand then `ui-select` offers event broadcast support also. You need to put broadcast event name in `focus-on` attribute of `ui-select` and brodcast that event by `$scope.$broadcast(...)`

```
<ui-select focus-on="UiSelectDemo1" ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" style="min-width: 300px;" title="Choose a person">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in ctrl.people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
          <small>
            email: {{person.email}}
            age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
          </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Call `$scope.$broadcast('UiSelectDemo1');` from button click or any other trigger/event.

Example taken from [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-focus.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your ui-select focused and opened after initialization:

```
yourModule.directive('uiSelectOpened', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'uiSelect',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, uiSelect) {
            $timeout(()=> uiSelect.toggle())
        }
    };
});
```

html:

```
<ui-select ... autofocus="true" ui-select-opened>...</ui-select>
```

Comment: Only answer that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and needed to add a directive

```
.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
    return {
      scope: {trigger: '@focusMe'},
      link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
          if (value === 'true') {
            $timeout(function() {
              element[0].focus();
            });
          }
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

then your ui-select add

```
 focus-me="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you are trying to achieve it from controller or directive (this method works independently and its completely angular way to do so) -

say ui-select is wrapped within div-

```
<div id="ui-select-wrapper">
    <ui-select>
        ...
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

Controller Method to setFocus -

```
var uiSelectWrapper = document.getElementById('ui-select-wrapper');
var focusser = uiSelectWrapper.querySelector('.ui-select-focusser');

var focusser = angular.element(uiSelectWrapper.querySelector('.ui-select-focusser'));

focusser.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use built in focus option! In controller put this code in needed method.

```
            if(yourform.$error.required[0].$$attr.focusOn){
                $scope.$broadcast(yourform.$error.required[0].$$attr.focusOn);
            }
```

And also define focus prop for ui-select

```
focus-on="UiSelectDemo1"
```